Which of these processes has higher priority?
Which of these processes had higher priority:
$ ps -o pri,nice -p 1525010
PRI  NI
 39 -20
$ ps -o pri,nice -p 1530075
PRI  NI
  0  19

The first one (1525010) called setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -20) the second one (1530075) called setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 99).
According to https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority: lower priorities cause more favorable scheduling, but -20 got priority 39 vs. 99 getting priority 0, which is higher.
Is this analysis correct?

Why are you setting a 99 niceness in the 1st place? The documentation clearly states that's not in range

@Destroy666 setpriority() clips priority argument value. I just checked with setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 19) and it is the same as setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 99).

Yes, but what's the point of using that value? Did you check with 2 valid/expected values?

@Destroy666 Yes, see above: I just checked with setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 19)


According to https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority: lower priorities cause more favorable scheduling

They do – as you can see from your output, setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -20) (the lowest possible input value) indeed resulted in a highest Linux scheduling priority.
The issue here is that the term 'priority' used in setpriority() actually refers to the niceness value, not to the Linux "native" scheduler priority.
The version of the getpriority(2) manual page you found is from 2012 (I don't think linux.die.net has updated its database since then); if you check a more up-to-date version here or here you'll find a clarification that "[t]he process attribute dealt with by these system calls is the same attribute (also known as the "nice" value) that is dealt with by nice(2)."
(See also getpriority(3p), which is the POSIX manual of the same functions.)

Thank you for the link, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887531/which-real-time-priority-is-the-highest-priority-in-linux The lower the PR, the higher the priority of the process will be, therefore PRI 39 is a lower priority than PRI 0.
